# zabbixのサーバとエージェントのバージョン違いによる値取得不可

Tags: zabbix

zabbixサーバを新設しました。

```
# zabbix_server -V
zabbix_server (Zabbix) 3.2.11
```

エージェントをこちらのzabbixサーバに向けました(/etc/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.conf設定で)。
しかし、

```
Get value from agent failed: cannot connect to [[0.0.0.0]:10050]: [111] Connection refused
```

ということで接続できません。
前に使っていたzabbixサーバは、

```
# zabbix_server -V
zabbix_server (Zabbix) 3.0.8
```

で/etc/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.confを元に戻し、エージェントを再起動すると問題なく繋がります。

ちなみにエージェントは、

```
$ zabbix_agentd -V
zabbix_agentd (daemon) (Zabbix) 3.0.10
```

です。バージョンの違いによって繋がったり繋がらなかったりするのでしょうか？
または他の原因でしょうか？

Zabbinx agent側の/etc/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.confの情報を載せておきます。
※ 注釈部分は削除。見せられない情報は<内容>に変えています。

```
PidFile=/var/run/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.pid
LogFile=/var/log/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.log
LogFileSize=0
Server=<Zabbixサーバ側IP>
ListenPort=10050
ListenIP=0.0.0.0
ServerActive=<Zabbixサーバ側IP>
Hostname=<Zabbixエージェント側ホスト名>
Include=/etc/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.d/
```

また暗号化でやってみました。

```
# zabbix_get -s <agentIP> -p 10050 -k "agent.ping" --tls-connect psk --tls-psk-identity "PSK 001" --tls-psk-file /etc/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.psk 
zabbix_get [19284]: Warning: SSL_shutdown() with <agentIP> returned error code 5: TLS read warning alert "close notify" 
zabbix_get [19284]: Get value error: connection closed during read zabbix_get [19284]: Check access restrictions in Zabbix agent configuration
```

こちらでもダメでした。
何かが制限されているのでしょうか。

ご存知の方、ご教示いただけると幸いです。

Comment: サーバ、またはエージェントでファイアウォール等は動作していますか？

Comment: 私もそれを疑いましたが、OSはCentOS7でfirewalldはinactiveになっています。また、agentサーバにtelnetをyum installしてtelnet <接続先> 10051をすると、Escape character is '^]'.Connection closed by foreign host.と出て一応、セッションは繋がっているようです。（新旧ともに）

Comment: confファイルの内容も質問文に載せておくと回答が付きやすいかもしれません。

Comment: 2つ前のコメント内容を修正します。Zabbixサーバからagentへは10050番なので、telnet <agentIP> 10050とすると、同様にEscape character is '^]'.Connection closed by foreign host.と出ます。これは繋がっていないということでしょうか？

Comment: 繋がらなければ、telnet: connect to address <agentIP>: Connection refusedと出るようなので、セッションは繋がっているようです。

Comment: Zabbixサーバから、zabbix_get -s <AgentIP>:10050 -k agent.pingとすると、zabbix_get [19093]: Get value error: cannot resolve [<AgentIP>:10050]とも出ました。

Comment: `-s <AgentIP>:10050` でなく `-s <AgentIP> -p 10050` では? https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.2/manpages/zabbix_get

Comment: zabbix_get -s <AgentIP> -p 10050 -k agent.pingを実行してみました。zabbix_get [19217]: Check access restrictions in Zabbix agent configurationとの表示です。agentで何かアクセスを制限してるということでしょうか？

Comment: 「Zabbix3.0の新機能として暗号化できるようになりました。」という記事を見つけました。http://328.hateblo.jp/entry/2016/02/27/194430　これは暗号化キーを使っていないので制限されているということでしょうか。

Comment: 追加情報はコメントで書き足すのではなく質問を編集して追記してください